# Trying to use a variable in a Set statement

Tags: vba

I have an array `oNam` of TextBox names, I want to call a sub and pass an index number pointing to the specific TextBox I am working on to the sub. In the sub I use the following code, `Dim MyControl As Control`, and `Set MyControl = Me![oNam(n)]`. I get the following

> Run-time error 2147024809: Could not find the specified object.

However, if I replace `oNam(n)` with the actual TextBox name, `Me![tbxBuyNowPrice]`, I don't get the error. I included a `Debug.Print oNam(n)` and it holds the correct name.

I've replaced the variable with the actual name and it works.

```vb
Dim oNam() As Variant

....Call TextBoxControl(34)


Sub TextBoxControl(n As Integer)
    Debug.Print oNam(n)           <====Shows correct name
    Set MyControl = Me![oNam(n)]  <====GET THE ERROR HERE 
    If DVAL(n) = "Yes" Then
        Call TextBoxSettings(MyControl, "", vbYellow)
        MyControl.SetFocus
        GoTo EndOfTextBoxControl
    Else
        Call TextBoxSettings(MyControl, 0, vbCyan)
    End If
EndOfTextBoxControl:
End Sub
```

Comment: The `!` syntax requires a literal name. For variable names, you need to use `Me.Controls(oNam(n))`.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. That worked like a charm. I've only been using vba for a couple of months (self-taught), so learning something new every day.